# Auto reconnection to TibcoEMS servers

Tags: c#, .net, tibco-ems

Do I need to implement anything to enable the "**retry to connect**" or "**failover to another server**"? From what I understand, these two should be taken care of as long as I configure them correctly (aka a fault-tolerant connection url and ReconnAttemptCount, etc.) However, it doesn't work for me.

My current scenario is that my app successfully connects to the EMS server, it can receive and send msg. Then I disable network connection, I can see exception "**TIBCO.EMS.EMSException: Connection has been terminated**" is thrown. Enable network connection but the connection to EMS server does not automatically restore.

Please help to advise. If my understand is wrong, please help to correct me as I am very new in this area.

Comment: Do you connect to the server programmatically?

Comment: Yes. I first create TIBCO.EMS.ConnectionFactory with all the required configurations, and then create TIBCO.EMS.Connection, and finally create TIBCO.EMS.Session

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234634/does-the-tibco-ems-server-manage-reconnection-or-does-the-client

Comment: If I understand correctly, that one is on the server side, aka the primary EMS server goes down, the client is switched to the secondary server without any impact. For my case, the network between client and server goes down. When it comes up again, the client does not automatically reconnect. So I wonder if I need to implement something to fix it, or I just miss something in the configuration

Comment: Please read carefully. The discussion in thread above is about single server.